# Add count column to df based on multiple values

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this:

```
p.vals          p.vals2         pvals3          
.006              1              .257
.25              .0002           .0178
.689             .0482           .117
.0027            .404            .0007
```

I want to add a fourth column that counts the values the meet the threshold pvalue of 0.05. Ideally I would end up with something like this:

```
p.vals          p.vals2         pvals3     count     
.006              1              .257        1
.25              .0002           .0178       2
.689             .0482           .117        1
.0027            .004            .0007       3
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can use: `df$count <- rowSums(df < 0.05)`.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the columns? My df also has columns I dont want to include. Sorry for not making that clear before.

Comment: Yes, you can remove the unwanted columns before doing `rowSums`. The best way depends on how many columns you want to remove,

Comment: Alternatively: `df$count <- rowSums(df[c("p.vals",  " p.vals2", "pvals3")] < 0.05)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

df |> rowwise() |> mutate(count = sum(c_across() < .05))
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Rowwise: 
  p.vals p.vals2 pvals3 count
   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1 0.006   1      0.257      1
2 0.25    0.0002 0.0178     2
3 0.689   0.0482 0.117      1
4 0.0027  0.004  0.0007     3
```

- data

```
df <- tructure(list(p.vals = c(0.006, 0.25, 0.689, 0.0027), p.vals2 = c(1, 
2e-04, 0.0482, 0.004), pvals3 = c(0.257, 0.0178, 0.117, 7e-04
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```